# Making a simple and local SMTP client withouth SSL

Tags: java, sockets, email, smtp

I'm running smtp4dev (http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) on my local computer and trying to write a simple Java program that sends a mail using SMTP.

But when I run it, the email is not received. smtp4dev recorded a session, but did not retrieve anything. Cant understand why, because when I do the exact same thing with telnet it works fine, but not with Java.

I'm also trying to print out to terminal what the server is replying, but it only gives me the first "220 localhost smtp4dev ready", and then nothing more.

This is my client:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    String hostName = "localhost";
    int portNumber = 25;
    String userInput = "";
    String mailFrom = "sender@server.com";
    String mailTo = "receiver@server.com";
    String subject = "Important matters";
    String data = "Finish your mission in 24h, sir. Or else...";

    try {
        Socket emailSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
            emailSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(emailSocket.getInputStream()));

        System.out.println(in.readLine());
        out.append("HELO" + hostName);
        out.append("MAIL FROM: <" + mailFrom + ">");
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
        out.append("RCPT TO: <" + mailTo + ">");
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
        out.append("DATA");
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
        out.append(data);
        out.append(".");
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
        out.append("QUIT");
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}  
}
```

}

Comment: you tried flushing the writer?

Comment: You don't appear to be sending newlines at the end of each chunk you send to the server. Each line sent to the server needs to end with CRLF, per standard NVT behaviour.

Comment: I tried to fix that now. By appending "\r\n" like this: `code`out.append("HELO\r\n");`code` `code` out.append("MAIL FROM: <" + mailFrom + ">\r\n");`code`
But it didnt change anything.